# How to make a loading button?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a button to be on loading animation until a function is done. Something like this:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)

function handleSave() {
      setLoading(true)

      for (let i = 1; i < 20000; i++) {};

      setLoading(false)

    }

 <Button
      loading={isLoading}
      disabled={isLoading}
      onClick={_ => handleSave()}>
      Save
</Button>
```

The button is from antd.

I`m a beginner and I don't know exactly how to do that. Do you have some recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `react-bootstrap`. There is no loading attribute for a button if I am not wrong. [Here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#button-loading-state) is the documentation on how to do a loading button

This is what you can do when render the button with different text when it is loading.

```js
<Button
    disabled={isLoading}
    onClick={handleSave}
>
{ isLoading ? "Loading": "Save" }
</Button>
```

You can include the [spinner animation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/spinners/) from `react-bootstrap` also.

```js
<Button
    disabled={isLoading}
    onClick={handleSave}
>
{ isLoading && <Spinner as="span" animation="grow" /> }
{ isLoading ? "Loading": "Save" }
</Button>
```

Comment: The button is from antd, sorry for not mentioning that. I added it now

Answer (score 0):

The using `setTimeout` is easier to simulate the delay when calling an API.

```
const handleSave = () => {
    setLoading(true）
    setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false)
    }, 3000) // run the callback function after 3000 milliseconds @ 3 secs
}
```